# Flat directory deployment for Qt 5 applications?

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt5

I'm deploying a Qt 5 application, compiled to windows. It turns out that some functionality is stored in plugins that are DLLs that have to be placed in a specific sub-directory, forcing me to use this structure:

```
applicaton directory
         |
         +------- platforms
         |           |
         +           +-------- qwindows.dll
         |
         +------- qpldrivers
         |           |
         |           +-------- qsqlite.dll
         | 
         +------- myprogram.exe, QtCore5.dll, etc.
```

I would like to flatten this directory so that qwindows.dll and qsqlite.dll (and any other future plugins) are stored in the same directory as my executable.

```
applicaton directory
         |
         +------- myprogram.exe, QtCore5.dll, qwindows.dll, qsqlite.dll, etc.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not.

Comment: I think Nicolas is right and it's not possible. See [QStyleFactory](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.4.0/src/widgets/styles/qstylefactory.cpp#L71) and [QPlatformPrintPlugin](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.4.0/src/printsupport/kernel/qplatformprintplugin.cpp#L44) as examples for hardcoded path names in the Qt source code.

Comment: @cloose I have found [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt-conf.html) in the meantime - seems like it should be supported there, but isn't. Do you think I should file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`addLibraryPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath):

```
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(".");
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("otherLibDir");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `qt.conf` file to customize were Qt looks for plugins.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html